# Fast DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

Is it possible to increase the performance of the `DensityPlot`?

For example, let's try to plot the following "flower"

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] Sin[10 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 10 ArcTan[x, y]]^4;

DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 MaxRecursion -> 3, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

This toy example takes about 12 seconds on my laptop, eats about 1GB of RAM while plotting, and the 34MB result slows down the notebook.

The questions are:

1. How to increase the speed?
2. How to decrease the `MaxMemoryUsed`?
3. How to decrease the size of the output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Edit:* tested with MMA 11.1, option `Exclusions -> None` added to recover  the previous behavior.

I have found that my approach with textures has different applications:

- [How to plot contours in the faces of a cube?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38688/4678)
- [How to plot ternary density plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39738/4678)

Now I want to use it for the enhancement of the `DensityPlot`:

```
Options[fastDensityPlot] = Append[Options[DensityPlot], Subpoints -> 30];
SyntaxInformation[fastDensityPlot] = SyntaxInformation[DensityPlot];

fastDensityPlot[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DensityPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
       Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Except@Subpoints]] // Normal // toTriangles // 
   texturize[Function[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@ {x, y, f},
        OptionValue[Subpoints], OptionValue[ColorFunction]]
```

Here `Normal` converts `GraphicsComplex` to separate polygons, `toTriangles` splits polygons to triangles, and `texturize` puts textures on every triangle (defined below), `f` is assumed to be `Listable`.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] Sin[10 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 10 ArcTan[x, y]]^4;

fastDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, ColorFunction -> Hue, Subpoints -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 600, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

This image looks a bit better. At the same time `fastDensityPlot` is ~10 times faster then the regular `DensityPlot`, `MaxMemoryUsed` is only 64MB and `ByteCount` is 10MB.

One can see that `fastDensityPlot` uses the advantage of the non-equidistant mesh:

```
fastDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, ColorFunction -> Hue, Subpoints -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 600, Mesh -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Definitions of the above functions:

```
toTriangles = # /. Polygon[v_ /; Length[v] > 3, ___] :> (Polygon@Append[#, Mean[v]] & /@ 
       Partition[v, 2, 1, 1]) &;

texturize[f_, n_, colf_] := # /. Polygon[{v1_, v2_, v3_}, ___] :> {Texture@
       ImageData@Colorize[
         Image@f[v3[[1]] + (v1[[1]] - v3[[1]]) #1 + (v2[[1]] - v3[[1]]) #2, 
                v3[[2]] + (v1[[2]] - v3[[2]]) #1 + (v2[[2]] - v3[[2]]) #2] 
          &[#, Transpose[#]] &@ConstantArray[Range[-1./n, 1 + 1./n, 1./n], n + 3], 
         ColorFunction -> colf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
      Polygon[{v1, v2, v3}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1 - 1.5/(n + 3), 
          1 - 1.5/(n + 3)}, {1.5/(n + 3), 1.5/(n + 3)}, {1.5/(n + 3), 
          1 - 1.5/(n + 3)}}]} &;
```

As in the linked answer, I add textures to every triangle with an appropriate rectangular grid. This method is fast because it uses packed arrays.

Comment: As I understand, you subdivide each triangle into `Subpoints`^2 regions and calculate values of `f` in the nodes. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes! More precisely, I calculate the texture for a parallelogram and use only a half of it. One can optimize it further, but it is no so simple.

Comment: So `PlotPoints->n, Subpoints->m, MaxRecursion->0` should be equivalent to `PlotPoints->n*m, Subpoints->0, MaxRecursion->0`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov [Yes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t3ds6.png), but with `Subpoints->1` in the second case.

Comment: With your screenshot I see that these plots are not identical. I also wonder why `ByteCount` for the first plot returns `883816` while for the second plot it gives `34814392`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov They are visually similar, but not equivalent. The second one contains a lot of small triangles with a lot of small textures. This is very slow and inefficient. `fastDensityPlot` is fast when you use a small number of big  triangles with big textures (two big triangles in the limit). The opposite limit is `DensityPlot` which produce a lot of small colorized (not texturized) triangles.

Comment: Now I got it, clever idea! But I should note that the restriction for `fastDensityPlot` accepting only a `PureFunction` which must contain only `Listable` functions makes it unusable for many practical applications where these requirements are unfeasible. This requirement also makes your code very difficult for debugging and understanding.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov There is no restrictions to pure functions. You can use a regular pattern definition `f[x_,y_] := ...`. Without `Listable` I will lose advantages of packed arrays. In any case you can: 1) add `Listable` attribute to `f`, 2) use `Interpolation` which is `Listable`, 3) `Compile` with `Listable` attribute.

Comment: When I evaluate `SetAttributes[f,Listable];
f[x_,y_]:=(x^2+y^2) Exp[-x^2-y^2] Sin[10 Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+10 ArcTan[x,y]]^4;
fastDensityPlot[f[x,y],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},PlotPoints->10,MaxRecursion->2,ColorFunction->Hue,Subpoints->20,PlotRange->All]` I get many error messages and empty graphics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12317/discussion-between-ybeltukov-and-alexey-popkov)

Comment: Hi, @ybeltukov. Your function seems doesn't work for mma 11.0.1.0. This is what I got https://pasteboard.co/avzFaWmrL.png

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work in *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows; for the first output shown I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ydqE.png -- any thoughts about that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice to see your comment again! Somehow the substitution in `toTriangles` does not work. Could you check the full form of your result? Is there any `Polygon[...]` expressions?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad you're here to talk to. :-)  Yes, in the InputForm of the graphic from my comment above there are many Polygon expressions, but it looks like your pattern doesn't match because of VertexColors?  Here's one: `Polygon[{{2.833333333333333, -2.8333333333333335}, {3., -2.666666666666667}, \
{2.666666666666666, -2.666666666666667}}, 
 VertexColors -> {Hue[1.236068478360077*^-6], Hue[4.324625545000996*^-6], 
   Hue[0.00002590501983329312]}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually `toTriangles` does nothing because this polygon is already a triangle. The problem is somewhere further. Does the final result contain texturized triangles of the form `{Texture[{...}],Polygon[{...},VertexTextureCoordinates->{...}]}`? If so, it is a frontend problem.

Comment: To my embarrassment the problem was localized to the region between the keyboard and the chair.  The definitions of `toTriangles` and `texturize` were being loaded from [(38688)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38688/121) rather than *this* answer.