# Create a torus with a hexagonal mesh for 3D-printing

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, 3d-printing

I am new to *Mathematica*, and I'm looking for a way to create patterns on the surface of 3D objects. One thing I have not been able to do is to create a hexagonal mesh on a torus. What I would like to have is a hexagonal mesh that has a certain thickness (so that it would be 3D-printable). So far, I have been able to create the torus itself. I am not sure of how to create the hexagonal pattern on the surface, and the process of mapping it onto the torus.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]},
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2UKIv.png) so far... I haven't figured out yet how to make the outer hexagons the same size as the inner ones.

Comment: @rm-rf I don't think you can have all the hexagons equally sized.

Comment: Can you use the meshing capability of the IMTEK Mathematica Package http://simulation.uni-freiburg.de/downloads/ims

Comment: I am lucky that all these efforts have been done a long time preliminarily before my request. That is the way mathematics usually works! The only question left: why we need 3 parameters to describe our object, what is actually
m?

Answer (score 70):

We can do this by building a regular hexagon tile and wrapping it onto a torus:

```
hexTile[n_, m_] := 
    With[{hex = Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2}, {k, 6}]] &},
        Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}] /. 
            {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 2 π {x/(3 m), 2 y/(n Sqrt[3])}
    ]

ht = With[{torus = {Cos[#] (3 + Cos[#2]), Sin[#] (3 + Cos[#2]), Sin[#2]} &},
    Graphics3D[hexTile[20, 20] /. Polygon[l_List] :> Polygon[torus @@@ l], Boxed -> False]
]
```

[image]

You can now convert this to a wire frame by changing the polygons to lines or tubes, whichever is convenient for you:

```
ht /. Polygon[x__] :> {Thick, Line@x}
```

[image]

```
ht /. Polygon -> Tube
```

[image]

Answer (score 50):

I propose a small modification of the parametrization for the torus that addresses issues with conformality.  Try

```
F[t_, u_, r_] := {Cos[t] (r + Cos[u + Sin[u]/r]),
                  Sin[t] (r + Cos[u + Sin[u]/r]),
                  Sin[u + Sin[u]/r]}
```

instead.  Next, we wish to choose suitable values for $m, n$ for a given $r$ such that the mapping of the regular hexagonal tiling preserves angles as much as possible.  We see that this requires us to choose $m, n$ such that $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \frac{n}{m} = r.$$  As we also require $n$ to be even (or else the tiling does not fit properly on the torus), we can let $n = 2k$ and this gives us $k \sqrt{3} = rm$; thus for a given $r$ we should try to choose $k, m$ as the nearest integers satisfying this equation.  This gives us a very nearly angle-preserving tiling.  For example, with $r = 2 \sqrt{3}$, we can choose $m = 11$, $n = 44$ to get something that looks like this:

[image: hexagonally-tiled torus]

Notice how much more regular the hexagons are throughout the torus--the "inner" ones are not squashed, and the outer ones are not stretched.

---

**Addendum**.  So, the above seems to work reasonably well for large $r$, but when $r = 1 + \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$, it doesn't work because the mapping I chose is not truly conformal.  I found the relevant information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152156).

This suggests that the correct form of $f$ should be

```
F[t_, u_, r_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], Sin[# u]/#} #^2/(r - Cos[# u]) &[Sqrt[r^2 - 1]]
```

And whereas $t$ is still plotted on the same interval, we need to plot $u$ on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}, \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{r^2-1}}\right)$.  So we modify the plotting command as well:

```
P[r_, m_, n_] := Graphics3D[Polygon /@ 
     Table[F[4 Pi/(3 n) (Cos[Pi k/3] + i 3/2),
           2 Pi/(Sqrt[3 (r^2 - 1)] m) (Sin[Pi k/3] + (j + i/2) Sqrt[3]), 
           r], {i, n}, {j, m}, {k, 6}], Boxed -> False]
```

And now the selection of $m, n$ based on $r$ is also more complicated.  $n = 2m \sqrt{\frac{r^2 - 1}{3}}$ seems to give good results.  Here is a picture for $r = 1.1$, $m = 30$, $n = 20$: [image: some hexagonally-tiled tori]

---

This solution calculates exact coordinates.  However, for 3D-printing, machine precision is usually enough, and affords a significant speedup.  We can force machine arithmetic by adding dots after some of the constants (e.g. `2 Pi` to `2. Pi`).  We can also achieve a 3× speed up by only calculating the location of each vertex once, and using `GraphicsComplex` to share the locations with each hexagon.  (This is how 3D formats like `.stl` work internally.  If you need regular polygon objects to process further, just use `Normal` to eliminate `GraphicsComplex`.)

```
Pfast[r_, m_, n_] := 
 Graphics3D[
  GraphicsComplex[
   Flatten[Table[
     F[2. Pi (i + k/3.)/n, Pi (1. + i + 2 j)/m/Sqrt[r^2 - 1.], 
      r // N], {j, m}, {i, n}, {k, {-1, +1}}], 2], 
   Polygon[Join @@ 
     Table[Mod[(j - 1) (2 n) + {1, 2, 3 + If[i == n, n (n - 2), 0]}~
         Join~({2, 1, If[i == 1, n (2 - n), 0]} + 2 n) + 2 (i - 1), 
       2 n m, 1], {i, n}, {j, m}]]], Boxed -> False]
```

The code is almost the same as before, except that we now only need to generate two new coordinates for each cell, so `Cos[Pi k/3]` only takes on two values and `Sin[Pi k/3]` only takes on one value, allowing the arithmetic to be simplified considerably.  We don't need to change `F`; it's already extremely fast due to the two-stage calculation it does to avoid recomputing the expensive square root multiple times.

We can do a timing and memory usage comparison of the two versions:

```
ByteCount[P2[2, 50, 100]] // Timing
(* {0.343750, 1440448} *)
ByteCount[P[2, 50, 100]] // Timing
(* {5.921875, 60849648} *)
```

The numerical version is around 20 times faster and gives a result 40 times smaller.   It's actually now fast enough to quickly make a nice table of tori with different parameters:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 ParallelTable[
  With[{n = 2 Round[m Sqrt[(r^2 - 1)/3]]}, 
   Show[P2[r, m, n], PlotLabel -> {r, m, n}]], {r, {1.1, 1.5, 2, 3, 
    5}}, {m, {6, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50}}], ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: more tori]

Comment: This looketh great! :D

Comment: I found that `n = 2 Round[m Sqrt[(r^2 - 1)/3]]` gives close to ideal shapes.  (found by optimizing one of the angles of the innermost ring of hexes)  Something like `GraphicsGrid[ParallelTable[With[{n = 2 Round[m Sqrt[(r^2 - 1)/3]]}, Show[P[r // N, m, n], PlotLabel -> {r, m, n}]], {r, {1.1, 1.5, 2, 3, 5}}, {m, {6, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50}}], ImageSize -> Full]` gives you an idea of how good your solution is to handling all types of geometries.

Comment: I was playing around with your code, and I've made a much faster/smaller version.  Mind if I append it to your answer?

Comment: Could you please explain what the symbols mean, e.g. {1,5,6,8} for the first in the table?

Comment: Is `P2` defined somewhere?

Comment: @samwolfe `P2 = Pfast`  Apparently, the function was originally `P2` and renamed to `Pfast` at some point; but subsequent calls to the function were not updated accordingly.

Answer (score 32):

There is an explicit formula

```
n = 30;
m = 10;

f[t_, u_] := {Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]};

Graphics3D[Polygon /@ Table[
  f[(4 π)/(3 n) (Cos[π k/3] + i 3/2), (2 π)/(Sqrt[3] m) (Sin[π k/3] + (j + i/2) Sqrt[3])], 
    {i, n}, {j, m}, {k, 6}]]
```

[image]

```
% /. Polygon -> Tube
```

[image]

I find it a bit simpler than rm -rf's solution.

Here `f` transforms from toroidal coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. Without `f` it is a plain hexagonal tiling

```
Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon /@ Table[{Cos[π k/3] + i 3/2, Sin[π k/3] + (j + i/2) Sqrt[3]}, 
   {i, n}, {j, m}, {k, 6}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As The Toad remarked in a (now deleted) comment, I have had some experience with building hexagonal meshes (after seeing previous work by Mark McClure). In fact, this was one of the reasons why I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/975) on generalizing `Partition[]`; I wanted to be able to construct a `GraphicsComplex[]` mesh that is easier to manipulate, and uses up less space than having things as explicit `Polygon[]`s. Thus, I shall now (partially) reveal how I did one of my earlier Gravatars:

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts : {__Integer?Positive}, offset : {__Integer?Positive}] :=
             Module[{n = Length[lst], k, offs},
                    k = Ceiling[n/Mean[offset]];
                    offs = Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[offset, k, offset]], 0];
                    Take[lst, #] & /@ 
                    TakeWhile[Transpose[{offs + 1, offs + PadRight[scts, k + 1, scts]}],
                              Apply[And, Thread[# <= n]] &]] /;
             Length[scts] == Length[offset];

multisegment[lst_List, scts : {__Integer?Positive}] := 
             multisegment[lst, scts, scts] /; Mod[Length[lst], Total[scts]] == 0

hexMesh[{uMin_, uMax_}, {vMin_, vMax_}, {n_Integer, m_Integer}, dirs___] := 
   GraphicsComplex[
           AffineTransform[{DiagonalMatrix[{uMax - uMin, vMax - vMin}/{3 n, Sqrt[3] m}],
                            {uMin, vMin}}] @
           Flatten[Delete[NestList[TranslationTransform[{0, Sqrt[3]}], 
                                   FoldList[Plus, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, 
                                            Table[Through[{Cos, Sin}[-π Sin[k π/2]/3]],
                                                  {k, 4 n + 1}]], m],
                          {{1, -1}, {-1, 1}}], 1],
           {dirs, 
            Polygon[Flatten[{multisegment[#1, {4, 2}, {3, 1}], 
                             Reverse /@ multisegment[Rest[#2], {2, 4}, {1, 3}]} & @@@ 
                           Partition[Join[{PadRight[Range[4 n + 1], 4 n + 2]}, 
                                     Partition[Range[4 n + 2, m (4 n + 2) - 1], 4 n + 2],
                                     {PadLeft[m (4 n + 2) - 1 + Range[4 n + 1], 4 n + 2]}],
                                      2, 1], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]]}]
```

That's one half of my secret. The other is in the use of a conformal parametrization of the torus. heropup used one particular conformal parametrization in his answer; mine is a touch different (previously used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26755); see [this paper](http://bridgesmathart.org/2011/cdrom/proceedings/134/index.html) for more details):

```
flatTorus[s_, t_][u_, v_] := {s Cos[(2 π u)/s], s Sin[(2 π u)/s], 
                              t Sin[(2 π v)/t]}/(Sqrt[s^2 + t^2] - t Cos[(2 π v)/t])
```

Here, then is a conformally parametrized torus on a hexagonal mesh:

```
With[{s = 21 3, t = 12 Sqrt[3]}, 
     Graphics3D[MapAt[(flatTorus[s, t] @@@ N[#]) &, 
                      hexMesh[{0, s}, {0, t}, {s, t}/{3, Sqrt[3]}], 1],
                Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: hexagonally-tiled torus]

Of course, I need to keep some secrets of my own ;), so let me finish this post with the following picture:

[image: a previous Gravatar]