# Hexagonal meshing in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, mesh

How can I include hexagonal meshing on a `Plot3D` such as this?

```
Plot3D[Sin[x], {z, -3, 3}, {x, -4 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: You may be able to use the answers from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39879/9490

Comment: I saw that, but I couldn't use that because that was used for graphic plot 3d and my plot is not graphic plot

Comment: I think its fair to say there is not a straightforward way to do this for a general function.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction:  https://pastebin.com/raw/NtSmn50x , based off the answer here:    https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77312/9490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [rm-rf's `hextile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39885/125) yet again

```
hexTile[n_, m_] := With[{hex = Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2},
  {k, 6}]] &}, Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}] /. 
    {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 2 π {x/(3 m), 2 y/(n Sqrt[3])}

ClearAll[plot3DwHexMesh]
plot3DwHexMesh[f_, n_: 20, m_: 20, s_: Yellow, o : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Graphics3D[hexTile[n, m] /. Polygon[l_] :> 
    {s, Polygon[l], Polygon[{Pi/5, 0} + {-1, 1} # & /@ l]} /. 
   Polygon[l_List] :> Polygon[{#, #2, f[#, #2]} & @@@ l], o, 
  Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Examples:

```
plot3DwHexMesh[Sin[#] &]
```

[image]

```
plot3DwHexMesh[Sin[# + #2] &, 20, 20, 
 Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]],  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this, and every variant I tried using `hexTile`, is that I couldn't find a way to respect the original `PlotRange`.  `plot3DwHexMesh` should, ultimately, take the `x` and `y` range into consideration, and show the `Axes` with the correct values.

Comment: @JasonB, right; I was puzzling over exactly those challenges. Not easy. Hence `False` as the default option value for `Axes`:)