# Create a templated double gyroid with a hexagonal mesh and etched hexagonal mesh

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I'm looking for a way to create patterns on the surface of 3D objects. One thing I have not been able to do is to create a hexagonal mesh on a templated double gyroid structure. What I would like to have is a hexagonal mesh that has a certain thickness. I am not sure of how to create the hexagonal pattern on the surface, and the process of mapping it onto the double gyroid structure. Additionally, the hexagonal mesh should be maintained with no filling.

`RegionPlot3D[(Sin[x]*Cos[y] + Sin[y]*Cos[z] + Sin[z]*Cos[x] >=  1.2 ||Sin[x]*Cos[y] + Sin[y]*Cos[z] + Sin[z]*Cos[x] <= -1.2), {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 200, Axes -> None, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> {RGBColor[0.7, 0.7, 0.7], RGBColor[0.7, 0.7, 0.7]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {Pi, Pi, 3}, Boxed -> False]`
[image]

Comment: seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39885/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77318/125)?

Comment: Thanks kglr. I have already found those items. However, how can I do the hexTile or hexagonal meshes on RegionPlot 3D..? Please comment to me.

Comment: I have been working with gyroids in Mathematica for several months, but I am not familiar with the concept of a templated gyroid. What kind of template?