# Create hexagonal mesh on 3D Parametric Plot and 3D spheres?

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

I am looking to put a cool geometric mesh on this object. I came across this question that explained how to put a hexagonal mesh on a parametric equation but I have a series of geometric objects of which use the Graphics3D sphere function along with the parametric equation function, here is the code and the link to the other question.

```
r := 1 - b^2;
w := Sqrt[r];
denom := b*((w*Cosh[b*u])^2 + (b*Sin[w*v])^2);

breather = {-.8 u + (2*r*Cosh[b*u]*Sinh[b*u])/
    denom, (2*w*Cosh[b*u]*(-(w*Cos[v]*Cos[w*v]) - Sin[v]*Sin[w*v]))/
    denom, (2*w*Cosh[b*u]*(-(w*Sin[v]*Cos[w*v]) + Cos[v]*Sin[w*v]))/denom};

s = Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.3]];
s2 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1]];
s3 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{2, 0, 0}, .7]];
s4 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{2.7, 0, 0}, .5]];
s5 = Graphics3D[Sphere[{3.3, 0, 0}, .33]];
s2n = Graphics3D[Sphere[{-1, 0, 0}, 1]];
s3n = Graphics3D[Sphere[{-2, 0, 0}, .7]];
s4n = Graphics3D[Sphere[{-2.7, 0, 0}, .5]];
s5n = Graphics3D[Sphere[{-3.3, 0, 0}, .33]];

c = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[breather /. b -> 0.7], {u, -6, 6}, {v, -40, 40}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> {60, 150}];

t = Show[s, c, s2, s3, s4, s5, s2n, s3n, s4n, s5n]
```

[image]
[Create a torus with a hexagonal mesh for 3D-printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/create-a-torus-with-a-hexagonal-mesh-for-3d-printing)

Comment: Are you sure that it is at all possible to tile the sphere with hexagons *only*?  With hexagons *and* pentagons it's possible, see e.g. bucky ball. It's relatively easy to see that a hexagonal tiling will work for the torus because it does work for the plane (rectangle) and there's an easy mapping from a rectangle to a torus.  But it is not at all obvious to me that this is possible with the sphere.  It's not possible to tile the sphere with rectangles without either having some ugly "cuts" or poles where the rectangle degenerate into tiny triangles (think lat-long lines).

Answer (score 3):

*Euler characteristic* `Vertices - Edges + Faces` for torus equals `0`.

So you can see that when you have `n` regular haxagons:

```
6n/3 - 6n/2 + n == 0 
  (*each vertex is shared between 3 polygons*)
  (*each edge is shared between 2 polygons*)
```

is fulfilled for any `n`. That is why it was relatively easy to do what is done in linked answer.

As Szabolcs has pointed out, sphere is different, here Euler characteristic is 2.

Immediately you can see that such simple mesh of regular hexagons can't fit.

So without further details we can't help you.

Comment: Hi@Victoria. I am afraid the hexagon detail may be lost in the narrow central areas near the axis during 3D printing.