# create an (almost) hexagonal mesh on an ellipsoid

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, mesh

**EDIT** 
I edited the question in order to take into @Kuba's comment.

I want to create this figure with Mathematica (in particular an *almost* hexagonal mesh on an ellipsoid; thanks to @Kuba I know this is not 100% possible).

[image]

I use the function `hexTile` defined by @R.M. as his reply in [39879](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/create-a-torus-with-a-hexagonal-mesh-for-3d-printing/85901#85901).

```
hexTile[n_, m_] := 
 With[{hex = Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2},
         {k, 6}]] &},       
  Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}] /. 
               {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> 
    2 \[Pi] {x/(3 m), 2 y/(n Sqrt[3])}]
```

E.g.

```
ht = With[{ell = {7 Cos[#1] Sin[#2], 5 Sin[#1] Sin[#2], 3 Cos[#2]} &},
   Graphics3D[
   hexTile[20, 20] /. Polygon[l_List] :> Polygon[ell @@@ l], 
   Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

How can we modify the function so that the distribution of hexagons and pentagons resembles closely that of the first image?

Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba. I accept the dublicate nature of the question, but still how we can get the same output as the first image with Mathematica?

Comment: @Kuba I have edited the question. I think now it is not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: voted to reopen :) let me leave the link to [100% hexagonal mesh on sphere problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79518/create-hexagonal-mesh-on-3d-parametric-plot-and-3d-spheres?lq=1)

Comment: I apologise for the incovience! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, we learn each day, it's not obvious it is not possible.

Comment: @Kuba: Should I simply delete this question and post a new one or simply wait for the reopening?

Comment: @Kuba: No problem:-)!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we compute the dual polyhedron of an appropriate triangularization of a surface we can get another polygonal mesh.  This is pretty much the same as [Kuba's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) approach except the code below computes the dual polyhedron more efficiently.

The basic function `iDual` computes the dual of a polyhedron given by a list of coordinates and lists of faces (by the indices of their vertices in the coordinate list).  (Technically, the function assumes some approximate regularity of the polyhedron and that it can be considered centered at the origin.  The mean of the vertices of a face serve as the "midpoint" of the face and form the vertices of the dual.  Polyhedra with folds in them are probably not going to work.)  The user-level function `dual` translates graphics and regions into input for `iDual`.  While there is combinatorial data for determining the ordering of vertices about a face of the dual, doing it numerically with `sortvertices` is both easier and faster.

```
ClearAll[dual, iDual, sortvertices];

sortvertices[coords_, normal_, face_] :=
  With[{proj = DeleteCases[
       Orthogonalize[
        Join[{normal}, N@IdentityMatrix[3]]
        ], {0., 0., 0.}][[2 ;; 3]]},
   SortBy[face, ArcTan @@ (proj.coords[[#]]) &]
   ];

iDual[coords_?MatrixQ, faces : {{__Integer} ..}] := 
  With[{nvertices = Max@faces, nfaces = Length@faces},
   With[{mat = SparseArray@ Flatten@Table[{v, f} -> 1, {f, nfaces}, {v, faces[[f]]}],
     dualcoords = Mean[coords[[#]]] & /@ faces},
    With[{dualfaces = mat["AdjacencyLists"]},
     Graphics3D@ GraphicsComplex[
       dualcoords,
       Polygon[
        Table[
         sortvertices[dualcoords, coords[[v]], dualfaces[[v]]],
         {v, Length@dualfaces}]]
       ]
     ]]];

(* user-level functions *)
dual[polyhedron : Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[coords_, Polygon[faces_]]] := 
  iDual[coords, faces];
dual[polyhedron_?MeshRegionQ /; 
    RegionDimension[polyhedron] == 2 && RegionEmbeddingDimension[polyhedron] == 3] := 
  iDual[MeshCoordinates[polyhedron], MeshCells[polyhedron, 2] /. Polygon -> Sequence];
dual[polyhedron_?BoundaryMeshRegionQ /; RegionDimension[polyhedron] == 3] := 
  iDual[MeshCoordinates[polyhedron], MeshCells[polyhedron, 2] /. Polygon -> Sequence];
```

Here is Kuba's example, with the dual vertices projected back onto the ellipsoid:

```
dual@DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> .02] /. 
 GraphicsComplex[pts_, stuff___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[(Normalize /@ pts).DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 3}], stuff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note region functions do not always produce an appropriate triangularization:

```
dual@ DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]]
dual@ DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, stuff___] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[(Normalize /@ pts).DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 3}], stuff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems impossible to use region functions directly on `Ellipsoid`:

```
dual@ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}], MaxCellMeasure -> .5]
dual@ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.03}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works on other polyhedra, too.

```
GraphicsRow[{#, dual@#}] &@ PolyhedronData@ "TruncatedDodecahedron"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  I've used this for triangulated spherical tilings and it works well.  +1

Answer (score 13):

Very inefficient but short:

I assumed that `DiscretizeRegion` of a `Sphere` gives us a mesh that have 5 or 6 triangles at each vertex.

```
 ms = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];

   (*groups of polygons with one common vertex*)
data = Sow[#, #[[1]]] & /@ MeshCells[ms, 2] // Reap // #[[-1, All, All, 1]] &;

data0 = MeshCoordinates[ms];

   (*this function replaces polygons which have common vertex
     with polygon composed of those polygons centroids.*)
reshape[list_] := #[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]] &@ Map[Mean[data0[[#]]] &, list]


Polygon[reshape /@ data] // Scale[#, {1, 2, 3}] & // Graphics3D
```

> [image]