# How to construct a 3D 10-sided Die (Pentagonal trapezohedron) and Spin to a face?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, polyhedra

The [Creating 3D dice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110295) question has answers for constructing a 6-sided die with images faces.  I need to construct a 10-sided die with numbered faces. My first thought was to find 10-side polyhedra using [`PolyhedronData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyhedronData.html).

```
PolyhedronData[10]
```

> ```
> {{"Antiprism", 4}, "AugmentedPentagonalPrism", "AugmentedTridiminishedIcosahedron", 
>  {"Dipyramid", 5}, {"Prism", 8}, "SquareCupola"}
> ```

Of these `{"Dipyramid", 5}` is the closest to the required shape of a [*Pentagonal trapezohedron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_trapezohedron).

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], Red, PolyhedronData[{"Dipyramid", 5}, "Faces"]}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is the *Pentagonal trapezohedron* in `PolyhedronData`?  If so how do I find it? If not, how do I go about constructing it? Might it be in [`LatticeData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LatticeData.html) in some form?

For the numbers I believe I need to isolate the faces and use [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) from a [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html)d text of the numbers.  However, I am not certain how to isolate the faces. This depends on the format of the polygon. Perhaps once I have the polygon format this will not be an issue.

Finally I need to spin the dice to a certain numbered face. I think I can figure this out with normals to the faces and a rotation matrix or maybe [`ViewPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html) of [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html).  However, suggestions are also welcome.

For context, this provide a visual to a random process.

Comment: The polygon is also on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalTrapezohedron.html) so I am hoping that it is somewhere in `PolyhedronData`.

Comment: There isn't a 3D graphics return from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=Pentagonal+Trapezohedron) on this, so I don't know if it is in the knowledge base.  You could grab [this d10 die model](https://grabcad.com/library/d10-dice-1) (you have to create a free account); it looks great but the mesh region imported has 5.6k polygons.

Comment: @JasonB Yeah, that has way too many polygons. I only need the 10.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Edit - forgot to add a necessary link*

Coincidentally I had a little personal project trying to make a good dice roller in Mathematica a while back.  Here's some of my code (note: this was before I learned a lot of efficiency techniques so it's not quick but it does make a fairly decent animation).  No apologies for the awful colour scheme though...

### Constructing the dice object

Makes a texture for the sides

```
plt[num_] := 
  ReliefPlot[
   Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Text[Style[ToString[num], Bold, 40, Underlined]], {Center, 
      Center}, {Center, Center}]];
```

Creates a single dice face

```
makeFace[num_] := {Texture[Image@plt[num]], 
  Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
       With[{n = Length[First[#1]]}, 
        Table[1/2 {Cos[2 \[Pi] i/n], Sin[2 \[Pi] i/n]} + {1/2, 
           1/2}, {i, 0, n - 1}]]}] &@
   Polygon[dat[[1, dat[[2, 1, num]]]]]}
```

Makes a `faces` sided dice by constructing each individual `GraphicsComplex`

```
dice[faces_] := Quiet[Module[{shape},
   shape = 
    Switch[faces, 4, "Tetrahedron", 6, "Cube", 8, "Octahedron", 
     10, {"Dipyramid", 5}, 12, "Dodecahedron", 20, "Icosahedron", _, 
     Missing["InvalidDice"]];
   dat = PolyhedronData[shape, "Faces"];
   If[Head[dat] === GraphicsComplex, 
    Graphics3D[{makeFace /@ Range[faces]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
     Boxed -> False], shape]]]
```

Tesing an 8 sided dice:

```
dice[8]
```

[image: 8 sided dice object]

### Rolling the graphic

Boundaries of the dice (this could be improved with `BoundingRegion`)

```
minz = Min[dat[[1, All, 3]]];
minx = Min[dat[[1, All, 1]]];
miny = Min[dat[[1, All, 2]]];
maxx = Max[dat[[1, All, 1]]];
maxy = Max[dat[[1, All, 2]]];
```

Redefine dice to be able to change viewpoint

```
dice[faces_, opts___] := Quiet[Module[{shape},
   shape = 
    Switch[faces, 4, "Tetrahedron", 6, "Cube", 8, "Octahedron", 
     10, {"Dipyramid", 5}, 12, "Dodecahedron", 20, "Icosahedron", _, 
     Missing["InvalidDice"]];
   dat = PolyhedronData[shape, "Faces"];
   If[Head[dat] === GraphicsComplex, 
    Graphics3D[{makeFace /@ Range[faces]}, Boxed -> False, 
     SphericalRegion -> True, opts], shape]]]
```

At this point I just copied out a bunch of nice viewpoints for each graphic, but you could probably automate this.  I'll attach the definition for the view locations but it's of the form `view = <| numberoffaces -> <|sidenumber -> viewpoint, sidenumber2 -> viewpoint2|>...|>` for each sidedness of dice.

[Here is the data (pastebin link)](http://pastebin.com/pGNF4rnp)

Now randomly choose a roll:

```
random[faces_] := 
 dice[faces, ViewPoint -> view[faces, RandomInteger[{1, faces}]]]
```

Add a bounce in (oh wow, I forgot how far I went with this...)

```
bn[n_] := Abs[Sin[n/(2 Pi)]]*n/30;
roll[faces_, opts___] := Module[{graphic},
  graphic = random[faces];
  Animate[
   Graphics3D[{Rotate[graphic[[1]], n Degree, {1, 1, 1}], 
     Polygon[{{{minx - 2, miny - 2, minz + bn[n]}, {maxx + 2, 
         miny - 2, minz + bn[n]}, {maxx + 2, maxy + 2, 
         minz + bn[n]}, {minx - 2, maxy + 2, minz + bn[n]}}}]}, 
    Sequence @@ graphic[[2 ;;]], opts], {n, -120, 0}, 
   AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> 60, 
   AppearanceElements -> None]]
```

The bounce is like this:

[image: Dice bounce shape]

### Putting it together

A single roll:

```
roll[faces_] := Module[{graphic, i},

  makeFace[
    num_] := {Texture[
     Image@Graphics[
       Text[Style[ToString[num], Bold, 30, Underlined]]]], 
    Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
         With[{n = Length[First[#1]]}, 
          Table[1/2 {Cos[2 \[Pi] i/n], Sin[2 \[Pi] i/n]} + {1/2, 
             1/2}, {i, 0, n - 1}]]}] &@
     Polygon[dat[[1, dat[[2, 1, num]]]]]};

  dice[n_, opts___] := Quiet[Module[{shape},
     shape = 
      Switch[n, 4, "Tetrahedron", 6, "Cube", 8, "Octahedron", 
       10, {"Dipyramid", 5}, 12, "Dodecahedron", 20, "Icosahedron", _,
        Missing["InvalidDice"]];
     dat = PolyhedronData[shape, "Faces"];
     If[Head[dat] === GraphicsComplex, 
      Graphics3D[{makeFace /@ Range[n]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
       Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, opts], shape]]];

  random[n_] := 
   dice[n, ViewPoint -> view[n, i = RandomInteger[{1, n}]]];

  graphic = random[faces];

  {Animate[
    Graphics3D[Rotate[graphic[[1]], n Degree, {1, 1, 1}], 
     Sequence @@ graphic[[2 ;;]]], {n, -120, 0}, 
    AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> 60, 
    AppearanceElements -> None], i}]
```

Trying that out:

```
roll[8]
```

[image: Rolling a d8]

The full application (you need to evaluate the `view` definition in the link):

```
CreateDialog[Pane[DynamicModule[{}, Row[{Grid[{
   {"Select dice: ", 
    Row[{"d", PopupMenu[Dynamic[num], {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20}]}]},
   {Button["Roll!", out = roll[num]; 
     AppendTo[history, {Text["d" <> ToString[num]], out[[2]]}]], 
    SpanFromLeft},
   {Dynamic[out[[1]]], SpanFromLeft}}], 
 Column[{Button["Reset history?", 
    history = {{Style["History", "Text", Bold, 14], 
        SpanFromLeft}};], 
   Pane[Dynamic[Grid[history]], {200, 400}, Scrollbars -> True], 
   Dynamic[If[Length[history] > 1, 
     Text["Mean: " <> ToString[N@Mean[history[[2 ;;, 2]]]]], 
     ""]]}]}],

Alignment -> Left,
BaseStyle -> {"Text", 14},
Initialization :> (history = {{Style["History", "Text", Bold, 14], 
    SpanFromLeft}};
 roll[faces_] := Module[{graphic, i},

   makeFace[
     num_] := {Texture[
      Image@Graphics[
        Text[Style[ToString[num], Bold, 30, Underlined]]]], 
     Append[#1, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
          With[{n = Length[First[#1]]}, 

           Table[1/2 {Cos[2 \[Pi] i/n], Sin[2 \[Pi] i/n]} + {1/2, 
              1/2}, {i, 0, n - 1}]]}] &@
      Polygon[dat[[1, dat[[2, 1, num]]]]]};

   dice[n_, opts___] := Quiet[Module[{shape},

      shape = Switch[n, 4, "Tetrahedron", 6, "Cube", 8, 
        "Octahedron", 10, {"Dipyramid", 5}, 12, "Dodecahedron", 
        20, "Icosahedron", _, Missing["InvalidDice"]];
      dat = PolyhedronData[shape, "Faces"];

      If[Head[dat] === GraphicsComplex, 
       Graphics3D[{makeFace /@ Range[n]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
        Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, opts], shape]]];

   random[n_] := 
    dice[n, ViewPoint -> view[n, i = RandomInteger[{1, n}]]];

   graphic = random[faces];

   {Animate[
     Graphics3D[Rotate[graphic[[1]], n Degree, {1, 1, 1}], 
      Sequence @@ graphic[[2 ;;]]], {n, -120, 0}, 
     AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRate -> 60, 
     AppearanceElements -> None], i}
  ];

   out = roll[8]
)]]]
```

[image: Dice roller]

Phew!  Didn't think I'd be posting that but there you go, maybe there are some bits you might use.

Comment: This is an amazing answer.  It is a great framework as well.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The pentagonal trapezohedron is the dual of the pentagonal antiprism:

```
PolyhedronData[{"Antiprism", 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, the dual is not in `PolyhedronData`:

```
PolyhedronData[{"Antiprism", 5}, "Dual"]
(*  Missing["NotApplicable"]  *)
```

So here's a function to compute the dual of a polyhedron. (It's an adaptation of `dual` for meshes in my answer to [create an (almost) hexagonal mesh on an ellipsoid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101183/create-an-almost-hexagonal-mesh-on-an-ellipsoid/101291?s=1|0.2041#101291) to polyhedra that have duals.)

```
ClearAll[dual, sortvertices, reciprocate];

sortvertices[coords_, normal_, face_] := 
  With[{proj = DeleteCases[
       Orthogonalize[Join[{normal}, N@IdentityMatrix[3]]], {0., 0., 0.}][[2 ;; 3]]},
    SortBy[face, ArcTan @@ (proj.coords[[#]]) &]];

reciprocate[face_?MatrixQ, r_: 1] /; Length[face] >= 3 := 
  r^2 {1, -1, 1} Most[#]/Last[#] &@ Reverse@ Last@ Minors@ Join[
       {{0, 0, 0, 0}},(* dummy row *)
       PadRight[face[[;; 3]], {Automatic, 4}, 1]
       ];

dual[polyhedron : Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[coords_, Polygon[faces_]]] := 
  With[{nvertices = Max@faces, nfaces = Length@faces}, 
   With[{mat = SparseArray@ Flatten@ Table[{v, f} -> 1, {f, nfaces}, {v, faces[[f]]}], 
         dualcoords = reciprocate[coords[[#]]] & /@ faces}, 
    With[{dualfaces = mat["AdjacencyLists"]}, 
     Graphics3D@ GraphicsComplex[
       dualcoords, 
       Polygon[Table[sortvertices[dualcoords, coords[[v]], dualfaces[[v]]],
         {v, Length@dualfaces}]]]]]];
```

The pentagonal trapezohedron:

```
dual@ PolyhedronData[{"Antiprism", 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a very useful function.  (+1)

Comment: @Edmund Thanks. Some of these `*Data[]` systems have standard operations that I wish such utilities were included in them, like `PolyhedronData["Dualize"][poly]` etc. (instead of relying on the data being present or not).

Comment: That is a great idea.  Perhaps you should suggest to WRI.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a start with defining your polygons.  [This page](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/PentagonalTrapezohedron.html) has coordinates for many different shapes.  I'm not familiar with the format, you may be able to import [this coordinates file](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/PentagonalTrapezohedron.txt) directly. But a little copy/paste, change indices to start at 1, and you have this

```
verts [C0_,C1_,C2_]:= {
    {0,C0,C1},{0,C0,-C1},
    {0,-C0,C1},{0,-C0,-C1},
    {1/2,1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2,-(1/2)},
    {-(1/2),-(1/2),1/2},{-(1/2),-(1/2),-(1/2)},
    {C2,-C1,0},{-C2,C1,0},
    {C0,C1,0},{-C0,-C1,0}};
faces={{9,3,7,12},{9,12,8,4},
    {9,4,2,6},{9,6,11,5},
    {9,5,1,3},{10,1,5,11},
    {10,11,6,2},{10,2,4,8},
    {10,8,12,7},{10,7,3,1}};
Graphics3D@GraphicsComplex[
    verts[(Sqrt[5]-1)/4,(Sqrt[5]+1)/4,(Sqrt[5]+3)/4],
    Polygon/@faces]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now all you need to do is apply textures.

Comment: That is a good resource.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Just posting a streamlined solution for the 6-sided case from the information I gained from @lowriniak very insightful post. It is easily expanded to other die.

It makes use of the normals to the faces for the view points which replaces the need for the predefined `view` association. Uses one `Graphics3D` with `Dynamic` changing `ViewPoint` and `Rotate`. Some manual adjustment of the `VertexTextureCoordinates` were made for this 6-sided case to have them upright when the animation completes.

```
dsDice = With[{faces = PolyhedronData["Cube", "Faces"]},
    With[{vertices = faces[[1, faces[[2, 1, #]]]]},
       <|
        "Face" -> {
          Texture[Image@
            Graphics[Text[Style[ToString[#], Bold, 100, Underlined]]]],
          Polygon[vertices,
           VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
            RotateLeft[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
             Switch[#, 1 | 2, 2, 5, 1, _, 3]]]
          },
        "NormalVector" -> 
         Subtract @@ vertices[[{1, 2}]]\[Cross]Subtract @@ vertices[[{1, 3}]]
        |>
       ] & /@ Range[6]
    ] // Dataset;
```

`dsDice` holds the faces and their normal vectors.

```
roll[] :=
 With[{event = RandomInteger[{1, 6}], spin = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 3]},
  {
   DynamicModule[{t = 1},
    Dynamic[
     t = Max[0, t - 0.03];
     Graphics3D[
      Rotate[Normal@dsDice[All, "Face"], t (5 \[Pi])/3, spin],
      ViewPoint -> Normal@dsDice[event, "NormalVector"],
      Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Boxed -> False, 
      RotationAction -> "Clip"]
     ]]
   ,
   event
   }
  ]
```

`roll` returns the animation that runs immediately and the face value of the roll.  The animation and `RandomInteger` call can be separated if the animation needs to be delayed.

Thanks again for all the answers. I'll be implementing the 10-sided case shortly.