# Making a 2D hexagonal mesh

Tags: graphics, mesh

There are a lot of answers for how to make a hexagonal mesh on a 3D surface but nothing on how to make a hexagonal mesh on a 2D surface. Can any provide code on how to do so? I am new to mathematica, and it is not so easy to simply convert the 3D hexagonal mesh code in [Create hexagonal mesh on 3D Parametric Plot and 3D spheres?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79518/create-hexagonal-mesh-on-3d-parametric-plot-and-3d-spheres)
or 
[Hexagonal Mesh on a 3D surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77312/hexagonal-mesh-on-a-3d-surface) to th 2D case.

I have been able to do

```
Ω = ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω];
```

but that is easy. I'd like to be able to mesh anything from a graphics region of the sort `Ω` to a parametric region like

```
Θ = ParametricPlot[a {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {a, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

If someone can please provide assistance, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Note that polygons are not valid mesh element in an `ElementMesh`.  They are valid for `MeshRegion`, though.

Comment: @nycguy92 Your formulations are not mathematically correct: "...hexagonal mesh on a 3D surface.." ->  hexagonal mesh on a 2D manifold embedded in 3D space. There is no such thing as "3D hexagonal mesh". Mesh is per definition a 2D object.

Answer (score 10):

Altering R.M.'s `hexTile` slightly, we get what is sought:

```
hexTile[n_, m_] := 
 With[{hex = Polygon[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2}, {k, 6}]] &}, 
  Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, hexTile[20, 20]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See [R.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/create-a-torus-with-a-hexagonal-mesh-for-3d-printing/39885#39885) to [Create a torus with a hexagonal mesh for 3D-printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/create-a-torus-with-a-hexagonal-mesh-for-3d-printing) for the defintion of `hexTile`, which is the function used in [kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77318/4999) to 
[Hexagonal Mesh on a 3D surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77312/hexagonal-mesh-on-a-3d-surface) that the OP linked.

Comment: Please se my related question, which uses your code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197855/2d-heaxgonal-lattice-points-with-center-points