# Hexagonal lattice points with center points in 2D

Tags: graphics, lattices

I am using the follwing coder from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109479/making-a-2d-hexagonal-mesh), answered by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), to create 2d lattice points, without the center ponts of the cells.

```
hexTile[n_, m_] := 
  With[{hex = 
     Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2}, {k, 6}] &}, 
   Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}]];
factor = 12;
coordinates = Flatten[hexTile[4, 10], 2]*factor;
ListPlot[coordinates, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

One problem here is that double coordinates are produced, which I don't need:

```
Length@coordinates
240

Length@DeleteDuplicates@coordinates
106
```

How can I modify the function `hexTile[n_, m_]` that no double coordinates are produced and how can I add center points to the hexagonal cells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an hexagonal lattice structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61834/how-to-create-an-hexagonal-lattice-structure)

Comment: A honeycomb lattice with the centers filled in is also called a triangular lattice; the question becomes what do you want to do about the boundaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
hexTile[n_,m_]:=With[{hex=Join[t=Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6]+#,Sin[2 Pi k/6]+#2},{k,6}],
{Median@t}]&},Table[hex[3 i+3 ((-1)^j+1)/4,Sqrt[3]/2 j],{i,n},{j,m}]];
factor=12;
coordinates=Union@Flatten[hexTile[4,10],2]*factor;
ListPlot[coordinates,AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated question. Do you know why there are a lot of duble coordinates produced? I find for your solution`Length@coordinates = 280` and `Length@DeleteDuplicates@coordinates = 146`

Comment: @lio I fixed the algorithm. now everything is fine