# Torus Hex Mesh - Need Unique Hex Dimensions

Tags: geometry, mesh, computational-geometry

I'm looking to laser cut a bunch of hexagons and assemble them into a torus (using hot glue or tape).  How do I get the dimensions of the individual unique hexagons?  I've seen [Create a torus with a hexagonal mesh for 3D-printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39879/create-a-torus-with-a-hexagonal-mesh-for-3d-printing) but it didn't help me.  I'd like to use n=30, m=10 and keep the hexagons conformally parametrized if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Can you explain why the link didn't help you? There are several examples there where you can get a Graphics3D object containing polygons, these you would be able to extract and get the dimensions.

Comment: How do I get the dimensions? I've never used Mathematica before so I'm clueless

Comment: I've tried using //InputForm and I got a long list of what look like coordinates but there's no way to know what order they are listed in                                                                      
   *Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[
   {{1.3600677225069995, -0.06787815808490266, 0.1162781963383075}, 
    {1.3829308389414996, 0., 0.}, {1.3760587449486854, 
     0.13769544562435124, 0.}, {1.3465507584441911, 
     0.20295987062409462, 0.1162781963383075}, 
    {1.3196511679801861, 0.33602447678540626, 0.1162781963383075},