# Multiple-colored regions on a Sphere in Mathematica

Tags: graphics3d

The problem: I would like to draw a sphere where the bottom half is one color, and the top half is split into 3 equal regions, each with its own color.

I have come up with the following code, by following the example from drawing a line on a torus here on Stack Overflow ([Plotting a contour on a torus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/plotting-a-contour-on-a-torus))

```
yourFunc = Function[{u, v}, v - Pi/2]
yourFunc2 = Function[{u, v}, u - 4 Pi/3]
yourFunc3 = Function[{u, v}, u - 2 Pi/3]
yourFunc4 = Function[{u, v}, u - 2 Pi]

ParametricPlot3D[{
    Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]
}, {
    u, 0, 2 Pi
}, {
    v, 0, Pi
}, 
MeshFunctions -> {
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, yourFunc[u, v]], 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, yourFunc2[u, v]],
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, yourFunc3[u, v]], 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, yourFunc4[u, v]]
},
Mesh -> {{0}},
MeshShading -> {
    {{{Red}, {Green}, {Blue}, {Yellow}}},
    {{{Orange}, {Cyan}, {Magenta}, {Black}}},
    {{{White}, {Black}, {White}, {Black}}}
},
MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick],
PlotPoints -> 100, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[3/5]
]
```

This will draw lines how I want it, but I have not been able to figure out how to draw each of the 4 regions with different colors. No matter how I played with it, I can only get 3. I've tried using MeshShading, as seen here, and also tried with a ColorFunction, but that didn't get me anything.

I hope that I'm making this more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 8):

**1.** The normal mesh functions are `u` (`#4 &`) and `v` (`#5 &`). So we can just use `Mesh` without special mesh functions.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
 Mesh -> {{0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}, {Pi/2}}, 
 MeshShading -> 
  Map[Directive[Opacity[0.6], #] &, {{Red, Green, Blue}, {Yellow, Yellow, Yellow}}, {2}],
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using `MeshStyle`, one also often has to set the `BoundaryStyle` to match.  The boundary comes from the boundary of the domain of the parametrization, not of the sphere.

**2.** If the mesh/boundary lines in the lower half are not wanted, then the lines will have to be parameterized individually and combined with a plot of the sphere with `MeshStyle -> None`.  **Edit--** Since the question came up, here's how to do the lines just around each patch:

```
lines = Table[
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]},
     {v, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]],
    {u, {0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}}] ~Append~
   With[{v = Pi/2}, 
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]},
     {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick]]];
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]},
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
  Mesh -> {{0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}, {Pi/2}}, 
  MeshShading -> 
   Map[Directive[Opacity[0.6], #] &, {{Red, Green, Blue}, {Yellow, Yellow, Yellow}}, {2}],
  MeshStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None],
 lines]
(* image essentially the same as the one below *)
```

**3.** Then for fun, a direct construction, which also isn't that hard for a sphere.  Note that `Partition[array, {2, 2}, {1, 1}]` partitions a 2D array into quadrilaterals -- a nice trick, although it needs some flattening and reordering.  It's also appropriate for our sphere.

```
sphere[u_, v_] := {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]};
sphericalpatch[{u1_, u2_}, {v1_, v2_}, dt_] := 
 Module[{n, pts = N@Table[sphere[u, v], {u, u1, u2, dt}, {v, v1, v2, dt}]},
  n = Length@First@pts;
  pts = Flatten[pts, 1];
  GraphicsComplex[pts,
   {Polygon[
     Flatten[
      Map[Flatten[#][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]] &, 
       Partition[Partition[Range@Length@pts, n], {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}], 1]
     ]},
   VertexNormals -> pts]
  ]

With[{dt = 2 Pi/48},
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], EdgeForm[],
   Red, sphericalpatch[{0, 2 Pi/3}, {0, Pi/2}, dt],
   Green, sphericalpatch[{2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}, {0, Pi/2}, dt],
   Blue, sphericalpatch[{4 Pi/3, 2 Pi}, {0, Pi/2}, dt],
   Yellow, sphericalpatch[{0, 2 Pi}, {Pi/2, Pi}, dt],
   Opacity[1], Green, Thick,
   Line[Table[sphere[u, #] & /@ Range[0, Pi/2, dt],
     {u, {0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}}]],
   Line[sphere[#, Pi/2] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, dt]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is instructive, esp`MeshShading` and progresses approach in question (so +1) The alternative of putting pieces together, which I used, seems easier to deal with (perhaps) unwanted 'longitude' lines, though I have to suppress the 0/2Pi seam of bottom hemisphere. :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Yes, yours works pretty well with the boundary, but it's not very hard to add the lines to mine via copy/paste/edit. The problem with combining several surface plots is that often there are little gaps, bercause the points on the boundaries usually do not coincide. (It happens with yours if you set all boundaries to `None`.  The thickness of the boundary hides the gaps.)  You don't get gaps with `MeshShading`.  (I hate that seam in the parametrized sphere - with or without the boundary. +1 to you, too)

Comment: agree gaps ... trade-offs.

Comment: really like 3...neat trick...always learning, btw used your ghost trails for recreation: http://wp.me/p1or7L-BD

Comment: @ubpdqn  Cool "signature"!

Answer (score 5):

```
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, ##, Mesh -> None] & @@@ 
  MapThread[{{s, Sequence @@ #1}, {t, Sequence @@ #2}, 
     PlotStyle -> #3} &, {{{0, \[Pi]/2}, {0, \[Pi]/2}, {0, \[Pi]/
      2}, {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}}, {{0, (2 \[Pi])/3}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, (
      4 \[Pi])/3}, {(4 \[Pi])/3, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}}, {Red, Green,
      Blue, Yellow}}], PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

or perhaps this is closer to intended final result:

```
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, ##, Mesh -> None] & @@@ 
  MapThread[{{s, Sequence @@ #1}, {t, Sequence @@ #2}, 
     PlotStyle -> {#3, Opacity[0.6]}, BoundaryStyle -> #4} &,
   {{{0, \[Pi]/2}, {0, \[Pi]/2}, {0, \[Pi]/2}, {Pi/
       2, \[Pi]}}, {{0, (2 \[Pi])/3}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, (4 \[Pi])/
       3}, {(4 \[Pi])/3, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}}, {Red, Green, Blue, 
     Yellow}, {Directive[Green, Thick], Directive[Green, Thick], 
     Directive[Green, Thick], None}}], PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the mesh lines are not needed, `SphericalPlot` can be used in a much simpler form:

```
sp1 = SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> {1, 2},
        MeshShading->Thread[{{Red, Blue, Yellow}, Green}], MeshStyle->None, Lighting->"Neutral"]
```

[image]

If you do need the mesh lines, you can do

```
sp2 = SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
        Mesh->{0, 2},  PlotStyle->None, MeshStyle->Directive[Thick, Green]]
Show[sp1, sp2]
```

[image]

Or, as in @ubpdqn's answer, define a function that takes 4 arguments to produce the two plots:

```
spF = SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, # π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> {#2, 2}, 
       MeshStyle -> #3, MeshShading -> #4, PlotStyle -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"] &;

args = {{1, 1, None, Thread[{{Red, Blue, Opacity[.8, Yellow]}, Green}]},
        {1/2, 0, Directive[Thick, Cyan], None}};

Show @@ spF @@@ args
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you another wonderful lesson, +1, of course:-). I should have read Mesh documentation for SphericalPlot3D...very nice

Comment: thank you indeed @ubpdqn; i just learned myself, thanks to your answer and Michael's, that default `MeshFunctions` for `SphericalPlot3D` is also `{#4&, #5&}`.