# How can I visualize a map $f:T^2\to T^2$?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, parametric-functions

Let $T^2\cong S^1\times S^1$ be the one-holed torus surface (say, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and say I have a simple-ish map $f:T^2\to T^2$ which I'd like to visualize. How might I do that?

To make this concrete, let $f(z,w)=(zw,z^2)$ where $z,w\in S^1$. I'd like to see a decent representation of the image of this map on $T^2$.

Here's what I know:

From a previous answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/plotting-a-contour-on-a-torus), I know I can visualize a torus in Mathematica (as well as plot a contour on it). For example, I can use something like

```
yourFunc = Function[{u, v}, Re[2 Exp[2 π I (u + 2 v)] + 3 Exp[2 π I (u - 2 v)]]];

ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 π v]) Sin[2 π u], 
   (2 + Cos[2 π v]) Cos[2 π u], Sin[2 π v]}, 
   {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
   yourFunc[u, v]], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], PlotPoints -> 50]
```

to visualize (on a torus) the contour corresponding to the zero-set of a provided parametric function:

[image]

However, this sort of example hinges on a 3D parametric representation of a torus rather than a *product of circles* representation and my knowledge is currently insufficient to bridge the gap.

**Edit:** Per a comment by @Rahul below: I'm considering $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, the map $f(z,w)$ can be converted to a map $[0,1]^2\mapsto[0,2]^2$ by converting: 
$$z=e^{2\pi i\theta},w=e^{2\pi i \phi}\implies zw=e^{2\pi i(\theta+\phi)}\text{ and }z^2=e^{2\pi i(2\theta)}.$$
So, equivalently, we have a map $g:[0,1]^2\to[0,2]^2$ given by $g(\theta,\phi)=(\theta+\phi,2\theta)$. Using `Mod`, we can visualize a parametric plot for the map $g$:

```
ParametricPlot[{Mod[u + v, 1], Mod[2 u, 1]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

yields

[image]

. Does this help? Note that I tried substituting

```
yourFunc = Function[{u, v}, {u+v, 2u}];
```

into the original snippet of code above but that doesn't work.

Comment: How is it S^1xS^2 and not S^1xS^1?

Comment: @BlacKow - Because I are not type good. ;) (fixed now)

Comment: You can draw a mesh on our original torus (that would be circles) and then draw (on the second torus) the result of your map applied to every circle

Comment: What is $zw$ when $z,w\in S^1$? Are we interpreting $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @BlacKow - I understand the idea/theory behind what you're saying, but is this something Mathematica can do programmatically? Could you possibly shed some light on the computational aspect in an answer?

Comment: @Rahul - Ah, yes. Good point. Here, I meant for the circle to be a subset of the complexes! I'll edit the question asap...unfortunately, I'm on the mobile app currently.

Comment: @Rahul: I've added more to the answer per your comment above.

Comment: @BlacKow: Does my addition make me any closer to the desired outcome?

Comment: @cstover I'm not sure what is your final goal. You want to visualize the mapping just in some way? I think making two toruses would be good visualization: first one has a circle defined by `v==const` and the second one has the path is the result of your mapping applied to the circle. You can also use `Manipulate` to make an animation. Are you interested in this particular mapping? Or you want a general solution?

Comment: @BlacKow - I don't have any particular goal, per se, and indeed, any sort of visualization will work. Your idea sounds great! If it wouldn't put you out too much, could you give an example of what the code may look like as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the patch around the left torus to see where it's mapped on the right torus by `func`.

```
func = Function[{u, v}, {u + v, 2 u}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
func = Function[{u, v}, {u + v, 2 u}];
nmesh = 10;
mesh = {(-0.5 + Range[-nmesh, 2 nmesh])/nmesh,
        (-0.5 + Range[-nmesh, 2 nmesh])/nmesh};
param = Function[{u, v},
   {(2 + Cos[2 π v]) Sin[2 π u], (2 + Cos[2 π v]) Cos[2 π u], Sin[2 π v]}];
With[{patch = First@ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, 0, 0.15}, {v, 0, 0.15}]},
  points = Transpose@patch[[1]];
  polygon = Cases[patch, _Polygon, Infinity];
  ];
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     param[u, v],
     {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
     PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> mesh],
    Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[
      Dynamic@Transpose[param @@ (p + points)],
      {Red, EdgeForm[], polygon}]]
    ],
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     param[u, v],
     {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 2},
     MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 1/2 (2 u - v)],
       Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, v/2]},
     PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> mesh],
    Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[
      Dynamic@Transpose[param @@ func @@ (p + points)],
      {Red, EdgeForm[], polygon}]]]
   }],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

The mesh is computed from the inverse function of `func`, i.e., `Solve[func[s, t] == {u, v}, {s, t}]`.  One might have to use `FindRoot` on complicated functions, which might also be quite slow.  In such a case, it would be faster to map forward lines in the domain torus, in the way the polygon is mapped onto range torus.

Comment: Thank you **so much**! This is far-and-away better than anything I would have thought possible (definitely anything I would have come up with on my own). This is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this independently as well.

First, I define a function which is projection to a torus of given inner/outer radii:

```
r1=1;r2=0.3;
f[{\[Theta]_,\[Phi]_}]:={(r1+r2*Cos[\[Phi]])*Cos[\[Theta]],
   (r1+r2*Cos[\[Phi]])*Sin[\[Theta]],r2*Sin[\[Phi]]};
```

My first step at visualizing such a map was to look at what it does to a lattice in $[0,1]^2$:

```
pts=6;
grid=Table[{i,j},{i,0,1,1/pts},{j,0,1,1/pts}];
grid2=Table[{Mod[i+j,1],Mod[2 i,1]},{i,0,1,1/pts},{j,0,1,1/pts}];
g=Graphics[Table[Arrow[{{i,j},{Mod[i+j,1],Mod[2i,1]}}], {i,0,1,1/pts},
   {j,0,1,1/pts}]];

Show[g, ListPlot[grid, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.015]]],
   ListPlot[grid2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.015]]]]
```

[image]

And on a torus:

```
grid3=Evaluate[f]/@Flatten[grid*2Pi,1];
grid4=Evaluate[f]/@Flatten[grid2*2Pi,1];

ptgrid=Evaluate[Point]/@grid3; 
ptgrid2=Evaluate[Point]/@grid4;
g2=Graphics3D[Table[Arrow[{grid3[[i]],grid4[[i]]}],{i,1,Length[grid3]}]];

Show[ListPointPlot3D[grid3, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.02]], 
   PlotRange -> All], ListPointPlot3D[grid4, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], PlotRange -> All], 
   g2, ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@f[{\[Theta], \[Phi]}], 
   {\[Theta], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25], PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

I later modified the above so that I could look at the orbit of a single point when the given function is iterated a given number of times.

Note that the above includes a number of ideas borrowed from various places online and so I definitely **don't** think it's concise, clean, or necessarily well-written.

I would still love to see other people's takes on this, though, so please chime in if you have other ideas, alternatives, etc.!

Comment: And yes, I later modified the `PlotRange` so that the torus wasn't cut off by the box. <(^_^<)